# Echo Value in Input, Once Value is Typed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to get this live search to work properly.

The way I envision it to work is, a user visits the form, enters in a value like `94302` and outputted is a box with "Santa Clara" for example, with a `value=""` equal to the value of the database field `fanDetLocID`.

**The HTML of the form**

```
<form method="post" id="FanDetail">
<input id="zip" name="zipcode" value="US Zipcode" onFocus="clearText(this)" />
</form>

<div class="success" style="display: none;">Saved!</div>
```

The jQuery which is called on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#zip").keyup(function() {
         // do magic
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/getFanLoc.php",
        data: "zip="+ zip,
        success: function(){
            $('#zip').function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();};
            }
        });
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

**The php file: getFanLoc.php which is called by jquery by method `.keyup()` when a 5-digit zipcode is entered**

```
 <?php
/////////////////////////////////////
require_once('../cfg/dbi.php'); /////
/////////////////////////////////////

############### SANITIZE ############### //////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$zip = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['zipcode']));   ///
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zipcode']); ///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    ## INSERT CLEAN DATA INTO TABLE…
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT fanDetLocID, fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocState FROM fanDetailLocation WHERE fanDetLocZip = ?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $zip);
    $sth->execute();
    if ($res = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        printf('%s, %s',
            htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocCity'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
            htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocState'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        );
    }   
} 





catch(PDOException $e){
    file_put_contents('../../PDODBConnectionErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
}



?>
```

Current Problem: I type in a 5-digit zipcode and nothing is displayed, I need help with getting this value to display upon entering in a 5-digit zipcode.

I've checked the SQL query and this works fine. It should output in the input box the values of `fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocCity` like Santa Barbara,CA for example.

Comment: I'm asking for possible ways to output this, I'm not asking for you to write my code. I'm here to learn, this type of response above isn't helpful.

Comment: this response is not intended to be "helpful". This is merely an explanation what's wrong with your question. You have to learn by means of some classes, or book, or tutorial. While this site is for asking certain questions. Got one?

Comment: In your Prepared statement, you are just including the variable instead of using the place holders and binding the value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your primary problem is that you are attempting to `echo` a [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). You need to perform at least one fetch operation and retrieve the values from the result set.

Secondly, you should **really** use bound parameters instead of injecting values into your SQL string.

Third, I see no point in getting the database to perform trivial string concatenation. Try this instead

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT fanDetLocID, fanDetLocCity, fanDetLocState FROM fanDetailLocation WHERE fanDetLocZip = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $zip);
$sth->execute();

if ($res = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    printf('%s, %s',
        htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocCity'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocState'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );
}
```

Comment: Great points here! Is it redundant to have `htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocCity'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocState'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` again since I used this before preparing the query ? This is not showing anything. Please see updated code, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The value of `htmlspecialchars($res['fanDetLocCity'],$res['fanDetLocState']` needs to SET to the value of `<input id="zip"`, upon entering in a 5-digit zip

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the jquery itself, this line inside `.ajax() data: "zip="+ zip,` could be erroneous since not data is sent to the URL of the page. Could this be the problem?